# Translation of "pantyliner"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

So, [pantyliners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantyliner) which differ from [sanitary napkin aka the famous "pad"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanitary_napkin), doesn't seem to have a specific word in Spanish.

What words are used in Spanish to mean "pantyliner"?

Comment: How about telling us how you'd like to use the term?  Do you need it to match perfectly with what's on the market in a particular country?  Is this simply to enable you to communicate effectively with a friend or relative?  Help us help you.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm not sure if they even exist on other countries, I know their existence due to reading wikipedia article on [feminine hygiene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminine_hygiene). I need as much information as I can get, it is sufficient with this: if there is a translation, and means the same product or the closest, I need at least one traslation, the answer given seems I will accept because satisfies that. I don't have to communicate with friends or relatives about this, but get online results in google by typing the translation this question will gave me. Thank you for your help

Comment: In Colombia [Protectores diarios](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=protectores+diarios&oq=protectores+di&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.6787j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is no Spanish entry for "pantyliner" in wikipedia (your linked source), there is one in [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=pantyliner), which translates as "pantiprotector"  and "salvaslips". None are in the DRAE. I think I have never heard of "pantiprotector" but may have heard of "salvaslips" (or even "salvaslip").

Nevertheless, I believe that the more widespread term used for "an absorbent piece of material used for feminine hygiene [...] worn in the gusset of a woman's panties [...] for daily vaginal discharge, light menstrual flow, tampon and menstrual cup backup, spotting, post-intercourse discharge, and urinary incontinence" is "[compresa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A3CdDjR)".

The term "compresa" can refer also to some sort of sanitary pad, but it also refers to the "compresa higiénica", which is

> 1. f. Tira desechable de celulosa u otra materia similar que sirve para absorber el flujo menstrual de la mujer.

Comment: I think "compresa" as you say means also sanitary pad made of clothes (thus non desechable) but again, it also other people say it for a desechable one. I thank you your translations seem helpful, thought I'll know with time if there is something more to say to the matter.

Comment: There is no regional tag on the question but fyi in Colombia we never heard of _compresa_ exept _compresas de agua fría/caliente_ which are used by athletes to calm sore muscles or injuries.

Answer (score 6):

The word you're looking for is "**[salvaslip](https://www.google.es/search?q=salvaslip&tbm=isch)**" or "**[protegeslip](https://www.google.es/search?q=protegeslip&tbm=isch)**".

"Compresa" (pad) is a more general term, but normally used to mean the thicker ones.
***Salvaslips*** are thinner and more discreet, but cannot absorb as much. Because of that, they are used only in the last days of your period, or in the days before as a protective measure against an unexpected start of it. Hence the name "salva slip" or "protege slip": they save/protect your panties from stains and give you some time to find a proper pad or tampon.

It is not in the dictionary (yet), but every woman will understand what you mean.

Comment: Thank you, this is VERY helpful indeed as the other answer, since it gives me one more word: "protege slip"

Comment: @Santropedro you should use a regional tag in this question because both answers so far do not apply to all Spanish speaking countries. I'm sure at least not for Colombia.. I see you are from Argentina but still accepted the other answer with less votes that looks like a good answer for Spain.

Comment: @DGaleano Yes, now it's late, but you are right in that I should have tagged Argentina. Now the answers wouldn't reflect ARgnetina so It doesn't make sense now. Maybe, should get separated into questions for every country specific.